# SonicWALL TZ215 and switch issues

Tags: sonicwall

Our IT guy is on vacation for a week, and after an hour on the phone with Dell trying to resolve the issue with no improvement, they gave up.

We have a SonicWALL TZ215 and a 3Com 16 port dual speed switch to run our simple office network. With nothing in the system changing in the last while, the Internet download speeds are 20% of what they should be as of last week.  Speeds directly at the modem are fine, likewise speeds directly at the SonicWALL are fine, and if you bypass the SonicWALL, speeds through the switch are fine.

The modem is plugged into x1 and the switch into x0 on the sonic wall.

Comment: Do you have the proper rights, and knowledge on how, to make changes on the SonicWALL?

Comment: Also, bypassing your firewall is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: You must see the logs on the SonicWall, something is cutting your bandwith, is some matter. Maybe an automatic upgrade i think??, or something like that??

Comment: I have the access and knowledge to make changes to the settings on the SonicWall... I've also saved a backup file to keep a record of the current settings

Comment: The firewall isn't bypassed... I just bypassed it temporarily to isolate the sonic wall from the system to see if the switch was the problem

Comment: That's what I was questioning but the Dell tech this morning confirmed that we have the correct firmware and updates... only thing I could think of that would randomly make a change to the setup

Comment: You can use the dashboard to monitor the CPU usage to see if it is overloaded, and you can track the packet rate and traffic to see if a particular flow is clogging up the works.

Comment: From your answer look like if you disable firewall the connection ok, then I guess the problem lies from firewall. Try to see log for details or try disable rule one by one until you see the rule that make problem. Can you explained more clearly about "if you bypass the sonic wall speeds through the switch are fine."?

Comment: Could you confirm that port speed negotiation is happening correctly? Try to force X0 to use 100 Mbps Full duplex instead of Auto negotiate... Are there any forms of traffic shaping being applied? Did you see any "funnel" icons in your firewall rules?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that something on the local LAN may be downloading/consuming a lot of traffic? How many computers do you have connected to your switch? (including any wireless clients from an AP)
What kind of ISP/internet/modem do you have? (xDSL, Cable, etc)
What are your normal expected speeds? What are you seeing now?
How are you testing? (eg. http://www.speedtest.net)
If nothing else has changed I suspect it is not that the SonicWALL is overloaded. (on the System, Status page what are the Connections and Connection Usage values? and the CPUs percentage?)

- If you have confirmed plugging directly into the modem = full download speeds (make sure to enable a software firewall!) then, you know the modem/ISP/internet is OK.
- If you connect just the SonicWALL to the modem (X1) and then connect directly to the SonicWALL (X0) with no switch = full speed, then you know the SonicWALL is likely OK.
- If you now connect the switch to the SonicWALL (X0) and still ONLY connect your test computer to the switch = full speed, then you know the switch is likely OK.

Note: when you say "if you bypass the sonic wall speeds through the switch are fine" do you mean that you have configured each computer with a public static IP (because bypassing the SonicWALL means no DHCP and no NAT from the router and many ISPs only provide 1 or 2 public addresses via DHCP).

- Try hooking up the SonicWALL to the modem and the switch and then only connecting ONE additional computer at a time, testing and waiting between each one. If one computer is infected or perhaps has a BitTorrent client running on it I would suspect a few minutes after being connected it may start pushing a lot of traffic.

Hopefully you will find one computer (or maybe several) that cause the the traffic to spike and decrease your download speeds.

- Try enabling basic **Reporting** (under Log, Reports): press Start Data Collection. With the computers all connected you can select Bandwidth Usage by IP Address to see which IP is using all the bandwidth.
- You can also use the **Connection Monitor** (which is under Dashboard latest firmware) to view live connections. You can filter based on Source IP (such as the top IP from Reports) and then see what connections that machine has open right now.
- You can also sort columns using Tx Bytes and Rx Bytes to see which IPs (source or destination) are sending or receiving the most data at this moment.

If you have tested each component individually and they all test OK (meaning don't cause an 80% drop in speed) the devices are probably not the problem, it's probably one of the computers.

You can also use something like LAN Speed Test (http://www.totusoft.com/lanspeed.html) to test speeds across your switch -- it's possible your switch (or a few ports) is dying under high load.